# How can I retrieve wireless password / passphrase windows XP

Tags: passwords

I used one program before when I forgot my dial up password, is there a programe like that which can retrieve wireless password / pass-phrase for me ?? Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[NirSoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/password_recovery_tools.html) has a variety of password recovery tools, depending on what you need.

From your question it looks you need either [WirelessKeyView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wireless_key.html) or [Network Password Recovery](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/network_password_recovery.html)

(*Note:* these retrieve the password which you have in your windows settings but cannot see, because it is under asterisks. They do not go cracking wep/wpa protections ... or anything of the sort. For that find specialized tools or linux distributions like [BackTrack](http://www.remote-exploit.org/backtrack.html)).

Comment: Looks like the WirelessKeyView (towards the bottom of the page) should do the trick.

Comment: I'd add that it gives you a hashed password, which while looking different, should still work.

Answer (score 4):

The NirSoft WirelessKeyView tool [recommended by Idigas](https://superuser.com/questions/92792/how-can-i-retrieve-wireless-password-passphrase-windows-xp/92793#92793) should do the trick for you. If you're using Windows 7, you can [view the wireless key without any additional software](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2009/11/14/retrieve-view-or-display-wireless-wep-or-wpa-wifi-network-security-key-or-password-in-windows-7/).

If you have access to the wireless router, you should also be able to reset the router to the 
factory defaults, and then set a new WiFi passphrase that way.

Personally, I have a piece of paper with the WiFi password taped to the bottom of the wireless router. I figure that, by the time someone's in my house to get that key, I've got bigger problems to worry about than a WiFi passphrase...

Comment: Good point! The only problem with the paper approach is that my router is on top of a closet, some 3.5m above the ground, and I don't usually like climbing up there to write a new password every time I change it (not often, but still ...). Nevertheless, having a password written in some file somewhere in your home directory (or wherever) can save a headache every once in a while. +1